# Find the count of repetitive string of characters in 2 consecutive cells in a array of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I identify duplicate consecutive cells, not in adjacent columns but adjacent rows like my sample below: 
In the same scenario mentioned above I need to know only if there would be the same string of characters in 2 consecutive cells and that I need to know how many times they are repetitive in 2 or more consecutive cells.... Remember conditional formatting does not help. I need the count

Comment: Sample seems to be lost. Edit and add.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem? You can upload a screenshot or sample file.

Answer (score 0):

A start is the make a new column with the following function for data in column A:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A3,A2)
```

This will count how many times the string in cell `B1` is found in cell `B1` and `B2`. So if there is a consecutive duplicate, it would show the number `2`.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned rows the range would be more like `A2:B2`

Comment: This only helps if there are only two columns to test. Doesn't sound like that's the case..